# Whether it means the end time of the SYBASE LICENSE?

Tags: sybase

I want to know the meaning of "2013.03010/permanent/0C94 6187 B194 DF07", Whether it means the end time of the SYBASE LICENSE?

---

**sybase log**

> 00:00000:00016:2011/01/03 14:15:37.02 kernel  SySAM: Checked in
>   license for 1 ASE_CORE `(2013.03010/permanent/0C94 6187 B194 DF07)`.
>   00:00000:00000:2011/01/03 14:16:53.08 kernel  SySAM: Using licenses
>   from: /home/sybase/SYSAM-2_0/licenses
>   00:00000:00000:2011/01/03 14:16:53.10 kernel  SySAM: Checked out license for 1 ASE_CORE
>   `(2013.03010/permanent/0C94 6187 B194 DF07)`.
>   00:00000:00000:2011/01/03 14:16:53.10 kernel  This product is licensed
>   to: BEV CORPORATION, an OEM license from Sybase, Inc.
>   00:00000:00000:2011/01/03 14:16:53.10 kernel  Checked out license
>   ASE_CORE    00:00000:00000:2011/01/03 14:16:53.10 kernel  Adaptive
>   Server Enterprise (Enterprise Edition)

Comment: A better way to find the details of your license is to use the **sp_lmconfig** command in the database. It will give you the details of what verions/options you have licensed as well as the expiration for any of the licenses. Detailed information about the command can be found in the [Sybase Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/BABFJGAJ.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This message does not mean that the license is expired or something. It only states that sybase found a valid license and checked it out. More information about the sybase license manager you can find here: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1009350